Flink Sql query that creates a MAP
I have a working Spark SQL query in this format :
String flinkSqlQuery =
    "SELECT " +
    "  MAP( " +
    "    'mId', memberId, " +
    "    'rId', IFNULL(readId, ''), " +
    "    'VIEWED', 1, " +
    "    'UDF1', UDF1(param1) " +
    "  ) AS requestContext, " +
    "  CAST(1.0 AS FLOAT) AS FIXVAL, " +
    "  CAST(0.0 AS FLOAT) AS RESPONSE " +
    "FROM testingTable";

I am trying to convert it into Flink Sql to run using Flink's Table API :
String flinkSqlQuery =
    "SELECT " +
    "  MAP( " +
    "    'mId', memberId, " +
    "    'rId', COALESCE(readId, ''), " +
    "    'VIEWED', 1, " +
    "    'UDF1', UDF1(param1) " +
    "  ) AS requestContext, " +
    "  CAST(1.0 AS FLOAT) AS FIXVAL, " +
    "  CAST(0.0 AS FLOAT) AS RESPONSE " +
    "FROM testingTable";

But I am encountering the following error :

Caused by: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException:
The main method caused an error: SQL parse failed. Non-query
expression encountered in illegal context

Please suggest if this is this the right way to create a MAP in Flink Sql.

The syntax used by Flink SQL for creating a map (or an array) involves square brackets rather than parentheses. So it should be like this, instead:
    String flinkSqlQuery =
        "SELECT " +
        "  MAP[ " +
        "    'mId', memberId, " +
        "    'rId', IFNULL(readId, ''), " +
        "    'VIEWED', 1, " +
        "    'UDF1', UDF1(param1) " +
        "  ] AS requestContext, " +
        "  CAST(1.0 AS FLOAT) AS FIXVAL, " +
        "  CAST(0.0 AS FLOAT) AS RESPONSE " +
        "FROM testingTable";

See the documentation for more info.

Is there not a bug in the documentation ?
MAP ‘[’ value1, value2 [, value3, value4 ]* ‘]’

Since the [] characters are used to bracket optional content, I believe '[' is an attempt to indicate that you literally use the [ character -- so I guess I'd generously describe this as confusing, rather than wrong.
